# Regex repeated groups

Tags: regex

I have this text:

```
<span id="3">

HELLO THERE
<span id="5">
Other stuff
<span id="6">
Other Stuff
<span id="7">
Other sutff
```

I need to grab just the `<span...>` elements after the `HELLO THERE` text. So in the above example, all the spans except for the one with id=3.

So I tried `(<span.+?>)+` which grabs all the spans. Next, I tried `HELLO THERE.+?(<span.+?>)+`, but that only grabs the first relevant one. So my question is, what is the right regex to use here?

Comment: There is [a very good post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/335858) about a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

### RegEx 1

Here, we can use several expressions that would get the desired `<span>` opening tags. For example, we can simply use:

```
\s(<.+)
```

with a space boundary on the left and a capturing group which would do that.

[image]

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ClqQkm/1/)

---

### RegEx 2

Another alternative which is more expensive with higher complexity would be:

```
([\s\S].*?)(<.+>)
```

[image]

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1shWI2/1)

### RegEx 3

Then, we can reduce the complexity and improve the performance with this expression:

```
([\s\S].*?)(<.+>)*
```

[image]

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IzhNqT/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

Here, we can also visualize our expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This regex will capture all the  tags after Hello There into the matching groups:

```
HELLO THERE(?:(?:.*?)(<span[^>]+>))+
```

- `HELLO THERE` - match the beginning
  Inside the non capturing group:
- `(?:.*?)` - match optionally any text until you find
- `(<span[^>]+>)` - the span tag - this one will be captured
- `+` - repeat the previous 2 steps until no other span tags can be found

You also need to set your matching options to dot matches new line.

Comment: Have you tested this regex? I think you may be surprised.

Comment: It only matches the last span (id=7)